# How to return nothing in IF condition of MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

In MySQL I am using IF operator to return "YES" if condition is valid and "NO" if it's not valid

```
SELECT IF(500<1000, "YES", "NO"); //RETURNS YES
```

I want to return nothing if the conditions is not valid. How can I do this?
I've tried using NULL but it just returns NULL

```
SELECT IF(1500<1000, "YES",NULL); //RETURNS NULL
```

How can I get an empty row?

Comment: maybe something like this: `SELECT IF(500<1000, "YES", "");` Empty String which shows as blank/nothing.

Comment: "How can I do this? I've tried using NULL but it just returns NULL" `SELECT IF(1500<1000, "YES",NULL); //RETURNS NULL` yes that is logical because the IF is false so NULL is returned.  see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/340e01/625

Comment: If null isn't the nothing you want, then what do you actually want? What do you mean by an "empty row"?

Comment: @Andrew No I don't want the NULL, I just want nothing to be returned if the condition isn't valid. Like right now there is row
--ASSUME EMPTY ROW WITH NO COLS--
I want nothing to be returned eg,
--NO ROW RETURNED--

Comment: In that case, you need to make your question clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just return an empty string

```
/* Returns YES because condition is true */
SELECT IF(500<1000, 'YES', '');


/* Returns blank (empty string) because condition is false */
SELECT IF(1500<1000, 'YES', '');
```

**EDIT:** Apparently, OP wants [nothing to be returned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52613158/how-to-return-nothing-in-if-condition-of-mysql/52613179?noredirect=1#comment92161055_52613179). We can check for the same `IF` condition in the `WHERE` clause to be **not empty**. Try the following:

```
/* Returns nothing if condition dont match */
SELECT IF(1500<1000, 'YES', '')  
FROM test_table 
WHERE IF(1500<1000, 'YES', '') <> '';
```

Comment: It returns an empty row, I want nothing to be returned

Comment: @D14TEN what do you mean by nothing ? No row to be returned at all ?

Comment: Yeah, like no row at all

Comment: @D14TEN check the edited answer now. In case of using `Group By`, you can alias the results of `If` condition, and use the alias inside the `having` clause also.

Answer (score 0):

You could always wrap it with a condition of checking the variable that determines if nothing should be returned.

```
select * from (select 3 > 4 as result) as result
where result > 0;
```

Comment: The subselect isn't necessary if this is operating on a table, but otherwise it is.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `HAVING()` operator in MySQL :

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT IF(500<1000, "YES", "NO")
)
subq HAVING (500<1000);
```

`WHERE` is certainly first thing I would try, but as this seems to be a proof of principle and not a real select query, `HAVING()` is more useful with group functions, if you are using one (such as `COUNT()`).

Answer (score 0):

If you want no row at all, then simply write:

```
select 'Yes'
from dual
where 1500 < 1000
```